# Sort Array to 1st min, 1st max, 2nd min, 2nd max, etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Write a JS program to return an array in such a way that the first element is the first minimum and the second element is the first maximum and so on.

This program contains a function which takes one argument: an array. This function returns the array according to the requirement.

Sample Input: `array=[2,4,7,1,3,8,9]`. Expected Output: `[1,9,2,8,3,7,4]`.

```
const arrsort=(arr)=>{
   return arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
}
const test=(arr)=>{
  arr=arrsort(arr);
  var arr2=[];
  var j=0;
  var k=arr.length-1;
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
    if(i%2===0){
      arr2.push(arr[j]);
      j++;
    }
   else{
      arr2.push(arr[k]);
      k--;
   }
  }
 return arr2;
}
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Your loop is too short:  `i<arr.length-1` should be `i<arr.length`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two indices, you could shift and pop the values of a copy of the sorted array.

```js
var array = [2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9]

const arrsort = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

const test = (arr) => {
    var copy = arrsort(arr.slice()),
        result = [],
        fn = 'pop';
    while (copy.length) {
        fn = { pop: 'shift', shift: 'pop' }[fn];
        result.push(copy[fn]());
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(test(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

After sorting array this would work

```
  myarr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  let  lastindex = myarr.length-1;
  for(let i = 1 ; i <= myarr.length/ 2; i = i+2) {
  ele = myarr[i];
  myarr[i] = myarr[lastindex];
  myarr[lastindex] = ele;
  lastindex--;
}
```

Final Output will be: [1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can first `sort()` the array in ascending order and then loop through half of the array. And `push()` the values at corresponding indexes.

```js
let arr = [2,4,7,1,3,8,9];
function order(arr){
  let res = [];
  arr = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => a-b);
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length/2); i++){
    res.push(arr[i],arr[arr.length - 1 - i]);
  }
  
  return arr.length % 2 ? res.concat(arr[Math.floor((arr.length - 1)/2)]) : res;
}
console.log(order(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array, then copy and reverse and push to another array

```js
const a = [2,4,7,1,3,8,9];
a.sort();
const b = a.slice().reverse();
const res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (res.length < a.length) res.push(a[i]);
  if (res.length < a.length) res.push(b[i]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Or use a Set

```js
const a = [2,4,7,1,3,8,9];
a.sort();
const b = a.slice().reverse();
const res = new Set();
a.forEach((e, i) => (res.add(e), res.add(b[i])));

console.log(Array.from(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways are available to do this. And my solution is one of themm i hope.

Find max and min value, push them into another array. And delete max, min from actual array.

```js
let array=[2,4,7,1,3,8,9];
let finalArray = [];
let max, min;

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  max = Math.max(...array);
  min = Math.min(...array);      
  
  finalArray.push(min);
  finalArray.push(max);
  
  array = array.filter(function(el) {
    return el != max && el != min;
  })
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two iterators after sorting your array, one goes ascending and the other goes descending, until they cross each other.

Here's the code:

```js
const array = [2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9];

const test = arr => {
  const result = [];
  const sortedArr = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (let i = 0, j = sortedArr.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
    result.push(sortedArr[i]);
    i == j || result.push(sortedArr[j]);
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(test(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using two pointer algorithm

```js
function getValue(arr) {
  const result = [];
  let start = 0,
    end = arr.length - 1;

  while (start < end) result.push(arr[start++], arr[end--]);
  if (start === end) result.push(arr[start]);

  return result;
}

const array = [2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9];
const sorted = array.sort();
console.log(getValue(sorted));
```